# XQuery- concat or string-join?

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

Below is the XML Structure.

```
<Docs>
 <Doc>
  <Title>Physics</Title>
  <Desc>
    <Part n="Part 1">
      <Chap c="1"/>
      <Chap c="2"/>
      <Chap c="4"/>
    </Part>
  </Desc>
 </Doc>
 <Doc>
  <Title>Physics</Title>
  <Desc>
    <Part n="Part 2">
      <Chap c="2"/>
      <Chap c="3"/>
      <Chap c="4"/>
    </Part>
  </Desc>
 </Doc>
</Docs>
```

The output, I am after is as follows-

```
<Title>Physics,#,Part 1 - 1,2,4</Title>
<Title>Physics,#,Part 2 - 2,3,4</Title>
```

I tried with various combinations using `concat` and `string-join` but all in vain :(

Comment: Your XML document is not correct. Could you please fix it first?

Comment: "I tried with various combinations" - please show _what_ you tried, so we can help you with the specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later at night, I played with it again and got the answer, though not the exact one I required, but will suffice my need -

```
let $a :=
<Docs>
 <Doc>
  <Title>Physics</Title>
  <Desc>
    <Part n="Part 1">
      <Chap c="1"/>
      <Chap c="2"/>
      <Chap c="4"/>
    </Part>
  </Desc>
 </Doc>
 <Doc>
  <Title>Physics</Title>
  <Desc>
    <Part n="Part 2">
      <Chap c="2"/>
      <Chap c="3"/>
      <Chap c="4"/>
    </Part>
  </Desc>
 </Doc>
</Docs>


for $x in $a//Doc
return 
<Title>{
concat($x/Title,"#", 
    string-join(
        ($x/Desc/Part/@n, " - ", string-join(($x/Desc/Part/Chap/@c, ""),",")),""))
}</Title>
```